# Make the selected images same as randomindex selected from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array **notes** having nine jpg's on it, and an array **items** nine label and nine url's on it.

this code has three boxes It selected 3 `items` randomly from an array items.

I have placed the randomly selected item's `label` inside 3 boxes, inside `<P>` tags, and corresponding image on background from array **items**

I have stored currosponding images of notes on randomIndex selection to array **notesselected** this is called to box002 img src

Class **box002** can be dragged and dropped to the corresponding number in four boxes displayed. then blue digit and background in box dissappears.

**I have a working code now**

**My problem is that I want the box002 item should be same as the box digit, now drop is form left side box onwards**

**ie if box002 digit is 2 the drop(leftmost box) should be blue 2 number with background url image2**

how to change my code to make this happen.

```js
    var array2 = [];
    var items = [{
        label: '1',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1'
      },
      {
        label: '2',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2'
      },
      {
        label: '3',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image3'
      },
      {
        label: '4',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image4'
      },
      {
        label: '5',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image5'
      },
      {
        label: '6',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image6'
      },
      {
        label: '7',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image7'
      },
      {
        label: '8',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image8'
      },
      {
        label: '9',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image9'
      }
    ];

    var notes = ['https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=1',
      'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2',
      'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3',
      'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=4',                                                                                                              'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=5',
      'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=6',
      'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=7',
      'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=8',
      'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=9'
    ];


    var tempimages = [];
    var notesselected = [];


    array2 = items.slice();

    var item;

    function rvalue() {

      ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
      boxtags = document.getElementsByClassName("box");


    for (var index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() *array2.length)

    item = array2[randomIndex];
    array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);

    try {
    ptags[index].style.visibility = "visible";
    ptags[index].textContent = item.label;
    ptags[index].dataset.itemIndex = randomIndex;

    tempimages.push({data: item,index: randomIndex
    });
    notesselected.push({data: notes[randomIndex],
    index: randomIndex});

    boxtags[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + item.url + ')';
    } catch (err) {
    console.log('Exception');
    }

      }

    var tlen = tempimages.length;
    }


    function displayAllImages() {
    try {
    if (tempimages.length == 0) {
    rvalue();
    }

    var arr2 = notesselected;
    item = arr2.shift();

    image = document.getElementById('slide');
        //image.src = "images/"+item.data.url;
    image.src = item.data;
    image.dataset.itemIndex = item.index;
    } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    }
    };

    $(function() {
    displayAllImages();
    });

    function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var el = document.getElementById(data);

    var x = document.getElementById("slide").dataset.itemIndex;
    var y = ev.target.dataset.itemIndex;


    if (x == y) {
    ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'initial';
    ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundImage = 'initial';
    ev.currentTarget.style.border = 'initial';
    var pParagraph = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;

    pParagraph.style.visibility = "hidden";

    item = this.item;
    var arrayvalue = item.dataindex;

    tempimages.splice(arrayvalue, 1);

    if (tempimages.length == 0)
    {
    rvalue();
    }
    displayAllImages();
      } 
    else {
    alert("WRONG PLACED");
    }
    }
```

```css
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .box {
      width: calc(10.3% - 4px);
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 2px solid #333;
      border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
      margin: -2px;
      border-radius: 0%;
      background-color: #99ffff;
    }

    .box {
      height: 15vh;
      display: inline-flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-size: contain;
    }

    .box002 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10.3vh;
      left: 40.98vw;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .box002 img {
      width: 14.0vw;
      height: 23.0vh;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    p {
      font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
      font-size: 30px;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      text-shadow: 2px 8px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px -5px 35px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
      color: #005ce6;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="containerr">
        <div class="pic" id="content">


    <div id="container">

    <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
       <p name="values"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11">
       <p name="values"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12">
       <p name="values"></p>
    </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
      <img src="" draggable="true" id="slide" border="rounded" />
    </div>
```

Comment: sorry, im struggling to understand because of your english

Comment: for a user side of view i will explain, thre round box at right can be dragged and droped to rectangrlboxes starting from left,  on dropiing the rectangle box digit and bcakgground dissappear if digit on round box and rectangle box is same

Comment: My problem is that on from level 2(second time loading values to rectangle boxes),  the digit appearing on round box does not match with the leftside boxes, even thought digits on roundbox and rectangle box are same it get deleted ondrop on second level

Comment: i think i understand now. you have so many issues with your script. first and most importantly, sometimes it works properly and sometimes it doesn't. in other words, you can sometimes drop numbers that don't match and it still works. you're going to have to give me some time to look over this since i'm busy with my own thing right now. send me a reminder in a little bit and i'll figure it out for you

Comment: How many levels are there? how do you define levels?

Comment: @just-code    till randomly tempimages from randomly selected items finishes,   ie array items has 9 items , we select 3 values randomly therefore three levels

Comment: @srapcode  how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have many things going wrong here:

1. Using index is a wrong idea, you can use the label as the key as you have unique item for each object.
2. Your displayAllImages returns wrong iterations, I have applied proper filter to display the random image from the available tempImages.

**Things you need to take care of:**

1. Assign proper levels
2. You can possibly use 1 array instead of 2 notes, items.

Here is the demo to resolve your problem to display the image right from the available items randomly.

I have added comments to the code, so you can check the changes.

```js
var array2 = [];
var items = [{
        label: '1',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1'
    },
    {
        label: '2',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2'
    },
    {
        label: '3',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image3'
    },
    {
        label: '4',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image4'
    },
    {
        label: '5',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image5'
    },
    {
        label: '6',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image6'
    },
    {
        label: '7',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image7'
    },
    {
        label: '8',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image8'
    },
    {
        label: '9',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image9'
    }
    
];

var notes = ['https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=1',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=4', 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=5',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=6',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=7',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=8',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=9'
];


var tempimages = [];
var notesselected = [];


array2 = items.slice();

var item;

function rvalue() {

    ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
    boxtags = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
    //if array length is 0 then we need to identify the game as completed
    if (array2.length === 0) {
        alert('Game completed');        
        return;

    }

    for (var index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length)

        item = array2[randomIndex];
        array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);

        try {
            ptags[index].style.visibility = "visible";
            ptags[index].textContent = item.label;
            ptags[index].dataset.itemLabel = item.label;

            //using label as an identity
            tempimages.push({
                data: item,
                label: item.label
            });
            notesselected.push({
                data: item.url,
                label: item.label
            });

            boxtags[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + item.url + ')';
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Exception');
        }

    }

    var tlen = tempimages.length;
}


function displayAllImages() {
    try {
    
        if (tempimages.length == 0) {
            rvalue();
        }
        
        if(tempimages.length === 0){
         image = document.getElementById('slide');
         image.style.display = 'none';
         return;
        }

        // getting random item from the available items
        var arr2 = tempimages;
        item = arr2[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr2.length)]        

        image = document.getElementById('slide');
        //getting notes item
        var dataURL = notes.filter(a => a.indexOf("?text=" + item.label) > 0)[0];
        image.src = dataURL;
        image.dataset.itemLabel = item.label;

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
};

$(function() {
    displayAllImages();
});

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {

    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");


    var x = document.getElementById("slide").dataset.itemLabel;
    var y = ev.target.dataset.itemLabel;
    //add improvisation box drag is valid
    if(ev.target.tagName === "DIV"){
       y =  ev.target.children[0].dataset.itemLabel;
    }
    


    if (x == y) {
        ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'initial';
        ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundImage = 'initial';
        ev.currentTarget.style.border = 'initial';
        var pParagraph = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;

        pParagraph.style.visibility = "hidden";

        item = this.item;
        tempimages = tempimages.filter(a => a.label !== item.label);

        if (tempimages.length == 0) {
            rvalue();
        }
        displayAllImages();
    } else {
        alert("WRONG PLACED");
    }
}
```

```css
body {
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .box {
      width: calc(10.3% - 4px);
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 2px solid #333;
      border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
      margin: -2px;
      border-radius: 0%;
      background-color: #99ffff;
    }

    .box {
      height: 15vh;
      display: inline-flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-size: contain;
    }

    .box002 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10.3vh;
      left: 40.98vw;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .box002 img {
      width: 14.0vw;
      height: 23.0vh;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    p {
      font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
      font-size: 30px;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      text-shadow: 2px 8px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px -5px 35px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
      color: #005ce6;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="containerr">
        <div class="pic" id="content">


    <div id="container">

    <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
       <p name="values"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11">
       <p name="values"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12">
       <p name="values"></p>
    </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
      <img src="" draggable="true" id="slide" border="rounded" />
    </div>
```

Comment: great explanation and it worked perfectly,  thanks brother

Comment: if i want take notes images from a folder "currency",   how to change  var dataURL = notes.filter(a => a.indexOf("?text=" + item.label) > 0)[0];
        image.src = dataURL;

Comment: @Jupiter You should debug it and check how to change it. Notes filter returns the url, you can do the same for the currency.